# BX Slider centers image in carousel when closing Colorbox

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, colorbox, bxslider

I am developing a site with a BX Slider carousel showing two images at a time. I also have the colorbox plugin to show additional content after a thumbnail is clicked.

I'm having an issue whereby after clicking a thumbnail to bring up the modal window, if you click 'next' and navigate to additional content in the modal window that's related to a thumbnail that isn't currently in the BX Viewport then when you close the modal window the related thumbnail appears centered in the BX viewport with half of each adjacent thumbnail visible too.

The thumbnails don't reset to their original positions either after this has occurred so scrolling them looks awful.

[image: BX Viewport Issue Screenshot]

Has anyone got any idea why this may happen and if there's a fix?

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to the site where you are developing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem, in jquery.colorbox.js(jquery.colorbox.min.js) or in page $(document).ready function change init options to:
returnFocus: false
trapFocus: false

Comment: Nice, Thanks buddy